Transit Visa Requirement for layover of 11 hours 55 minutes at Riyadh Airport - Saudi Arabia for Indian Nationals
Indian National
Travelling from Delhi to Zurich via Riyadh with Saudia Airlines
Layover at Riyadh - 11 hours 55 Minutes
Leaving Airport Premises - No
Travelling back to India with Saudia Airlines
Zurich to Delhi Via Riyadh
Layover at Riyadh - 11 hours 30 minutes
Leaving Airport Premises - No
Please guide!
